# Movie where there is a chase with the camera attached in the front of the car

Tags: identify-this-movie

I don't remember too much about the movie, I think that the beginning was boring but with this chase scene the movie changed so I forgot the boring part

I remember that the camera it's attached outside the car, can't remember if this car it's being chased or chasing someone

- I think that there are no cuts while they are running
- I think that is a muscle car
- I think that is the only chase in the movie
- I think that is an american movie, maybe 2010 or more

EDIT: As I said, there are no cuts and I forgot to add that the only thing that you see it's the street because the camera is in front of the car, I think that the camera is not on the hood, maybe the camera is between the headlights

Comment: Lucky guess, could be Drive with Ryan Gosling: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780504/

The chase is here on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1vpwxtH9Hk

Comment: @FranciscoV. I also thought that it was that movie, but see my edit, there are no cuts and you only see the street

Comment: [This scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9cpFzKF2u7c) from [*Getaway (2013)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2167202/combined), perhaps? Continuous and rather low pov shot.

Comment: @Walt that's the scene that I'm talkin about, a really bad movie but I liked very much this scene, thank you!

Comment: No problem. I'll put it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [Getaway](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2167202/combined) from 2013 with Ethan Hawke and Selena Gomez.

> Getaway is the gritty, exciting action thriller from Warner Brothers in which former race car driver Brent Magna is pitted against the clock as he commandeers a custom Shelby Super Snake Mustang, taking it and its unwitting owner on a high-speed adventure at the command of a mysterious villain on a race against time to save the life of his kidnapped wife.

The movie features a lot of road action and here's that continuous POV shot you wanted: